# nhibernate mapping list of strings

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have entity SampleObject with following properties

```
SampleObject.cs
    Guid Id {get; set;}
    string Name {get; set;}
    IList<string> Images {get; set;}
```

I tried to map these ImagePathUrls property like these

```
Map(x => x.Images, ("ImagePathUrl")).Length(255);
```

Ofcourse on database side I have table with column `ImagePathUrl` of type `nvarchar 255`.

On debugging I getting following error

```
Could not determine type for: System.Collections.Generic.IList`1
[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(ImagePathUrl)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mapping List to string column.

```
HasMany(x => x.Images).WithKeyColumn("SampleObjectId").WithTableName("SampleObjectImages").AsElemen‌​t("ImagePathUrl");
```